# Loading JSON into Mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, import, mongoimport

I'm trying to load an 80 meg JSON file into mongodb using the following command:

`mongoimport --db qt --collection cftable --type json --file cftable.json --jsonArray`

What I get from mongoimport is the following:

`2014-05-12T14:16:00.338-0500 check 0 0
2014-05-12T14:16:00.338-0500 imported 0 objects
encountered 1 error(s)`

Here's what a sample record looks like - there are roughly 65,000 of these.  None approach 16 mg.  The entire file is 80 mb.  Is there a way I can break down the import in a way that would allow me to narrow down the problem?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree with mongoimport to do something like this?

`[
    {
        "last_name": "Jones",
        "first_name": "Johny",
        "middle_name": "J.",
        "nick_name": "",
        "gen_qual": "",
        "degree": "Ph.D.",
        "specialty": "LabM & Path",
        "voting_staff_flag": "1",
        "start_date": "Jan  1 1900 12:00:00:000AM",
        "end_date": "Dec 31 2599 11:59:00:000PM",
        "time_code": "All Day",
        "resident_or_fellow_flag": "0",
        "smtp_address": "Jones.Johny@mayo.edu",
        "per_id": "12345678",
        "rank": "Cons",
        "committee_member": "Y",
        "point_entity": "Somewhere",
        "s_last_name": "JONES",
        "s_first_name": "JOHNY",
        "ALT_IDENTIFIER_1": "JONESJ",
        "ALT_IDENTIFIER_2": "MRE2222",
        "ALT_IDENTIFIER_3": "SO_ST_02_50-EP",
        "ALT_IDENTIFIER_4": "123456",
        "campus_name": "Somewhere, Ohio",
        "work_locations": [
            {
                "w_ai": 17395220,
                "work_location_sort": 15,
                "building": "Rexell Building",
                "floor": "2",
                "area": "Experimental Pathology",
                "pager": "111 or (11)5-5555",
                "phone": "(11)9-9999",
                "supports": [
                    {
                        "support_sort": 0,
                        "support_desc": " ",
                        "support_note": " ",
                        "support_phone": " ",
                        "support_start_date": "",
                        "support_end_date": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "w_ai": 174956,
                "work_location_sort": 25,
                "building": "Rexell Building",
                "floor": "2",
                "area": "Laboratory",
                "pager": "111 or (11)1-1111",
                "phone": "(11)2-2222",
                "supports": [
                    {
                        "support_sort": 15,
                        "support_desc": "Medical Secretary",
                        "support_note": " ",
                        "support_phone": "(11)6-6666",
                        "support_start_date": "Jan  1 1900 12:00:00:000AM",
                        "support_end_date": "Dec 31 2599 12:00:00:000AM"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
'''
]`

Comment: is there a way to get the error message that is returned?

Comment: I guess that's part of my question - the only thing "returned" that I am aware of is what I posted above... didn't see any flags for establishing an error log, etc.

Comment: See if you can get the last error. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/

Comment: How did you create the file you are importing? Did you use mongoexport or does it come from some other source?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get the last error after I pick up my kid from school :-)  Martin - the json was constructed via a python script I wrote that parses bcp data from a denormalized table in Sybase. Randomly selected sections pass jsonlint, but I'm still thinking it all goes back to a format error.

Comment: try running mongoimport with the -vvvv option (more v's mean more verbosity) - may help narrowing down what the problem is

Comment: Thanks, the -vvvv option was what I was looking for.  It identified some flakey json (albeit "legal" according to jsonlint) that will be a problem even if it isn't *the* problem.  Thanks for the help, folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would insert your record into MongoDB, do a mongoexport -- and compare that file against your file.

Comment: I felt as if this is a good enough idea to qualify as an answer, but the devil was actually in broken json deep in the bowells of my 3 million+ rows.  I changed my python parsing code accordingly, and the whole thing ran fine.  I was able to get more info with the -vvv flag, but not enough to identify the broken json - I finally ran across that via cut/pastes to jsonlint.com.